# Ribbon Overflow Effect Issue

Tags: css, wordpress, ribbon

I'm creating a custom theme in wordpress. I have found up a code to get a ribbon effect around the titles of items on the sidebar. However, the ribbons aren't quite flowing over the edges of the sidebar, instead they're in the middle of the sidebar and when I float the title right, part of the ribbon gets  hidden. I've been playing around with it with the google chrome "inspect element" aspect, but can't quite to seem to get it working. What should I do? Link of site here: gamedaymeetup.com

```
    h1.widget-title {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;    
    margin: 0 -30px 30px -30px;
    padding: 10px 0; 
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    background: #5c5c5c;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.3), rgba(255,255,255,0));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.3), rgba(255,255,255,0));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.3), rgba(255,255,255,0));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.3), rgba(255,255,255,0));
    background-image:  linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.3), rgba(255,255,255,0));
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
```

}

```
h1.widget-title:before, h1:after
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent;
    bottom: -10px;
}



h1.widget-title:after
{
    border-width: 0 0 10px 10px;
    border-left-color: #222;
    right: 0;
}
```

and here's the sidebar sytling

```
#sidebar {
text-align: left;
display: block;
padding: 9px;
float: right;
width: 246px;
height: 100%;
font-family: "Gotham SSm A", "Gotham SSm B", Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 16px;
letter-spacing: .2px;
background-color: #FFF;
background-position: bottom;
color: #000;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-left-style: inset;
border-left-color: #C3C3C3;
```

}

Comment: link? html? Going to need something that actually displays what is happening and what you expect to happen. Can you create a jsfiddle to show what you're doing?

Comment: http://gamedaymeetup.com/ I'm new here on StackOverFlow. Not sure what a jsfiddle is.

Comment: jsfiddle.net it's a way of putting up sample code for people to see, test and play around with. Not relevant here. I'd edit the link into your question so others can see it because honestly I'm not seeing a way to fix this, I assume you want those ribbon things to go outside the main body, and I'm not sure how to do that since it's forcing them outside the actual wrapper too. For the record... lose the comic sans font, it's horrid and pretty much despised by most of the design community lol

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I really was just messing around with the fonts, it's not the finished product. I am trying to get it to look more professional so I'll find something more fitting when I get to it. Right now, i'm still trying to figure this ribbon thing out. I see it on websites all the time. nfl.com for instance has the ribbons hanging off the edge. Also, I got my ribbon code from here: http://www.red-team-design.com/css-ribbons.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with Chris Coyier's ribbon css from CSS Tricks: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/ribbon/

He worked out most of the edge cases from what I've seen. I used it on a production and didn't have much of a problem with it.